# How would I stop a button Click Event if value already exists in Generic Sortedlist?

Tags: c#

So my problem is that when I am doing my validation, my value of the datetimepicker gets added no matter what I've tried. I want to use my error msg and not a try catch, and i don't want the already existing value to go to my listbox. I am sure there is a easy way to solve this problem but I am at the student level. Thanks in advance to anyone who can steer me in the right direction.

```
SortedList<DateTime, string> task = new SortedList<DateTime, string>();

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;

        if (task.ContainsKey(dateTimePicker1.Value))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Already exists, sorry ");
            lstTaskList.Items.Remove(dateTimePicker1.Value);
            btn.Enabled = false; // just testing something
        }

        if (txtTaskDescription.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Task Description!");
            return;
        }            
        task.Add(dateTimePicker1.Value, txtTaskDescription.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < task.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime key = task.Keys[i];
            string val = task.Values[i];

            // MessageBox.Show("key: " + key + " val " + val.ToString());
        }
        lstTaskList.Items.Add(task[dateTimePicker1.Value]);

        //lblScreen.Text = dateTimePicker1.Text + tas
        //lstTaskList.Items.Add(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToLongDateString());
        //MessageBox.Show(task.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be an excellent problem to learn to use the **[awesome step debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**  You should also take the [tour] to see what ought to happen once you get an answer as on all your past posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to me that the method just needs to `return` before adding the item. For example:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    DateTime keyToAdd = dateTimePicker1.Value;

    if (tasks.ContainsKey(keyToAdd))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Already exists, sorry ");
        return;
    }
    tasks.Add(keyToAdd, txtDescription.Text);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! I just started using the return keyword earlier, I don't fully understand it. So, basically it returns it from the method if the condition is true?

Comment: The `return` keyword means that code will stop executing at that point and control returns to the caller immediately. If you enclose `return` within an `if` block it will only execute of the if condition is true.